# throw statement is showing error when i don't use invalid_argument

Tags: c++, exception

Whats the difference between :
 `throw invalid_argument("n and p should be non-negative");`
and 
 `throw ("n and p should be non-negative"); //This shows error when i write this statement in place of above statement;`
in given code below

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;



class Calculator {
    public:
        int power(int n, int p){
            if(n>=0 && p>=0){
                return pow(n, p);
            }
            else 
            {
                throw invalid_argument("n and p should be non-negative");
            }


        }
};

int main()
{
    Calculator myCalculator=Calculator();
    int T,n,p;
    cin>>T;
    while(T-->0){
      if(scanf("%d %d",&n,&p)==2){
         try{
               int ans=myCalculator.power(n,p);
               cout<<ans<<endl; 
         }
         catch(exception& e){
             cout<<e.what()<<endl;
         }
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the description of "error" ? Is it a compile error?

Comment: You may look up documents about [throw](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw)

Comment: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'                                                                                  
Aborted (core dumped)  This is the error if i replace